# Do I need a visa or pre-arrival registration to go to Macau via Hong Kong?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, hong-kong, macau

I am planning a trip to visit Macau by flying to Hong Kong and and go from the airport to the ferry terminal for the ferry that goes through outer Macau. I don't want to enter Hong Kong itself.

What documents are required? I have my Indian passport, air ticket from Delhi to Hong Kong (round trip) and confirmed hotel bookings in Macau. Are these  sufficient, or do I need anything else (like pre-arrival registration for Hong Kong and ferry bookings, too)?

Comment: http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/passengers-transiting-to-prd-ports.html

Comment: @mkennedy +1 great answer; add and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3):

From [HKIA website](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/passengers-transiting-to-prd-ports.html) (retrieved 7 June 2017):

> To PRD and Macao
>
> For transfer passengers who would like to take
>   ferries to the Pearl River Delta (PRD) / Macao, please proceed to the
>   ferry ticketing counters located at Transfer Area E2 and DO NOT go
>   through immigration procedures and reclaim baggage. Passengers who
>   have gone through immigration procedures CANNOT return to the ferry
>   ticketing counters and use the ferry service.
>
> To use the service, passengers must:
>
> Possess the following items:
>
> - Same day arrival flight air ticket / e-ticket / boarding pass stub;
> - A valid ferry ticket; and
> - A valid passport and, if applicable, a visa for intended destination (China / Macao).
>
> Transfer to PRD / Macao within the same day of
>   arrivals;
>
> Arrive at the Ferries to Mainland / Macao Ticketing Counter
>   located at Transfer Area E2 at least 60 minutes before scheduled ferry
>   departure time for ticketing and transfer procedures. For passengers
>   without checked baggage, 30 minutes would be sufficient.

There is an associated [Chinese/English flowchart](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/ferry-fortchart.html) as well.

Its steps are:

> Purchase ferry ticket and present baggage tag receipt at the Ferries to Mainland/Macao Ticketing Counter at Transfer Area E2
>
> Scan ferry ticket and check your baggage status at the ferry boarding entrance
>
> Board the Automated People Mover to SkyPier
>
> Board ferries to PRD & Macao ports (note: PRD is Pearl River Delta ports)